# "make -j 4: command not found" when invoking make from a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I'm having trouble adding ***`-j 4`*** to my make command. Its causing my Bash script to fail with:

```
./cryptest.sh: line 208: make -j 4: command not found
ERROR: failed to make cryptest.exe
```

Here's the Bash that determines when to add ***`-j 4`***. It seems to mostly be working:

```
# $MAKE is already set and either 'make' or 'gmake'
CPU=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -c '^processor')
if [ "$CPU" -gt "1" ]; then
    echo "$CPU processors, using \"$MAKE -j $CPU\""
    MAKE="$MAKE -j $CPU"
fi
```

Then, the Bash that invokes it and cause the error:

```
"$MAKE" static dynamic cryptest.exe 2>&1 | tee -a "$TEST_RESULTS"
if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" -ne "0" ]; then
        echo "ERROR: failed to make cryptest.exe" | tee -a "$TEST_RESULTS"
fi
```

There are similar questions on Stack Overflow with other commands, like [Execute command as a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19786259), but its not obvious to me how to simply append the command's arguments to the command. And doing the obvious results in errors like above, so questions like [How can I concatenate string variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4181703/608639) don't seem to work in this instance.

How do I append ***`-j 4`*** to ***`$MAKE`***?

---

I also tried the following,:

```
MAKE="$MAKE" "-j $CPU"
```

But it resulted in:

```
./cryptest.sh: line 186: -j 4: command not found
```

---

Finally, there's 50 to 75 of these:

```
export CXXFLAGS="..."
"$MAKE" static dynamic ...
```

So I want to fix 1 `"$MAKE"`, and not 50 or 75 uses of it.

Comment: Are you doing this in windows? On MS-DOS, the ‘-j’ option has no effect, since that system doesn’t support multi-processing. If the ‘-j’ option is followed by an integer, this is the number of recipes to execute at once; this is called the number of job slots. If there is nothing looking like an integer after the ‘-j’ option, there is no limit on the number of job slots. The default number of job slots is one, which means serial execution (one thing at a time).

Comment: @user3589054 - It is Linux. In this case, its a Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Server. The script is at [cryptest.sh](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptest.sh).

Comment: Why do you use double quotes in `"$MAKE" static dynamic ...` ?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to run the command named "make -j 4", not the command "make" with arguments "-j" and "4". In this case, you would run your command with simply

```
$MAKE static dynamic cryptest.exe 2>&1 ...
```

that is, without quoting the expansion of `$MAKE`. However, in general you should not store command invocations in a variable, only command *names*. Store the arguments in (preferably) an array.

```
MAKE=make
MAKEARGS=( -j 4 )

"$MAKE" "${MAKEARGS[@]}" static dynamic cryptest.exe ...
```

Comment: Thanks Chepner. So I am clear... I invoke make *without* the quotes using ***`$MAKE`***, and I form the command with ***`MAKE="$MAKE -j 4"`***. Is that correct?

Comment: @jww: Yup, that's the trivial fix; but it's not a very robust or extensible approach, which is why this answer is longer than that.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable